# Adaptive and Non Adaptive PRF

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Is it possible to construct a PRF that is secure under non-adaptive queries but not secure under adaptive queries?

Comment: Can you embed a value into the PRF, at a point that's easy to find by querying the PRF, but hard to predict without being able to query?